# Ingres SQL select multiple rows into one column

Tags: sql, ingres

Our database is on Ingres II 10.0.0 (su9.us5/132). As such, it is missing many useful functions like stuff, coalesce, etc that make merging multiple rows of data into one column supremely difficult.

There was this: [How to GROUP_CONCAT in Ingres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795370/how-to-group-concat-in-ingres) but that solution isn't possible with how our data is structured.

Essentially there is a table that has a reference number and each row can contain that reference number multiple times if they have multiple statuses.

For example:
123         ABC
123         DEF
123         GHI
189         ABC
189         GHI

I'm pulling data from multiple tables into the one select statement, and this is just part of the data I am after. So I want the 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI' for example to be selected into one column, rather than ending up with three rows of the duplicate person for each status they have.

I am yet to find an option that can work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to achieve this using a row-producing procedure.

Here's a quick example, which you can tweak to suit your needs. If you're expecting the concatenated results to be lengthy, don't forget the max length of a varchar is 32000.

```
create table myx(a integer not null, b char(3));
insert into myx values(123,'ABC');
insert into myx values(123,'DEF');
insert into myx values(123,'GHI');
insert into myx values(189,'ABC');
insert into myx values(189,'GHI');

create procedure myproc
result row r(a integer not null, b varchar(1000))=
declare aval=integer;
        bval=varchar(1000);
        newa=integer;
        newb=char(3);
begin
  aval=NULL;
  bval='';
  for select a,b into :newa, :newb from myx order by a,b
  do
    if :aval != :newa or :aval is null
    then
      if :aval is not null
      then
        return row(:aval, :bval);
      endif;
      aval = :newa;
      bval = :newb;
    else
      bval=:bval+','+:newb;
    endif;
  endfor;
  if :aval is not null
  then
    return row(:aval, :bval);
  endif;
end;

select * from myproc();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest upgrading to Actian Ingres 11.2, which have included the [LISTAGG()](https://docs.actian.com/ingres/11.2/#page/SQLRef/Aggregate_Functions.htm) function, as well as a lot of [new features](https://docs.actian.com/ingres/11.2/index.html#page/RelSum/New_Features_in_Ingres_11.2.htm#ww203708). This aggregate function is very similar to GROUP_CONCAT.